# One problem about the villages(Probability theory).

Tags: probability

The taxi driver drives through four villages $W,Z,X,Y.$ These roads form a quadrangle where $WX = 5, WZ = 10, ZY = 5$ and $XY = 10.$ With a probability of $\dfrac{1}{4},$ a call (order) may come. Then, with a probability of $\dfrac{1}{3}$, he can go to any village. Let $D$ (random variable) be the distance you need to travel to pick up to pick up and take one passenger. Find the probabilities of a random variable.

Solution:

Let the sides of the triangle be equal $a = 5, b = 10, c = 5, d = 10.$
$$\begin{cases} 
0 + a=5, \text{with the probability } 1/12\\
0+ b=10,\text{with the probability } 1/12\\
a + a = 10, \text{with the probability } 1/12\\
a + b = 15, \text{with the probability } 1/4 \\
b + b = 20, \text{with the probability } 1/12 \\
2a + b = 20, \text{with the probability } 1/6 \\
b + 2b = 25, \text{with the probability } 1/6 \\
2a + 2b = 25, \text{with the probability } 1/12 \\
\end{cases}$$

Why is it correct, namely this one  $2a + b = 20, \text{with the probability } 1/6 $?

Comment: Most of what you've written here is incomprehensible. "Let the sides of the triangle be equal $a=5$, $b=10$, $c=5$, $d=10$." So, there's a triangle with *four* sides? "$0+a=0$, with the probability $1/12$" How can you have $0+a=0$, when you've written $a=5$? and where does probability $1/12$ come from?

Comment: I didn't understand why this is (1/12), so it was in the answer?

Comment: "$b+2b=25$" – is that supposed to be $a+2b=25$? "$2a+2b=25$" – is that supposed to be $2a+2b=30$? But even with those corrections, I don't know what's going on.